# MongoDB add new/update field timestamp for all the records

Tags: python, mongodb, csv

I'm copying huge CSV file data into mongodb. I have totally 5 columns in csv now i want add new field  'Timestamp' : current_time (date cmd output).

Which is the best  way to achieve this and how, before inserting to mongodb or while inserting any how ?

I'm using almost similar to below code to write to db:
https://gist.github.com/mprajwala/849b5909f5b881c8ce6a

What i have is :

```
 A      B            C       D      E         
 Jack   08/03/1865  Yes    City1   Company1
 Sam    07/11/1881  Yes    City2   Company1
 Lina   18/02/1990  No     City3   Company1
```

what i want is :

```
 A      B            C       D      E         Timestamp
 Jack   08/03/1865  Yes    City1   Company1   1514446225
 Sam    07/11/1881  Yes    City2   Company1   1514446225
 Lina   18/02/1990  No     City3   Company1   1514446225
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your code is based on the example code, you can update the data_json before you store it (I believe that is the best way for that).

```
    ...    
    data = pd.read_csv(file_res)
    data_json = json.loads(data.to_json(orient='records'))
    for doc in data_json:
        doc['timestamp'] = timestamp
    db_cm.remove()
    db_cm.insert(data_json)
```

Comment: is it better to  for read each row then insert or before inserting to mongo db just read the csv and add another column ?  
Can we add new column to csv each row with same value

Comment: By default is it possible to add timestamp now() for json.loads()